# Output values in column1 the time as per value specified in column2 sql using Tally table

Tags: sql, join

Input :

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 2 |
| D | 1 |

Output :

| col1 |
| --- |
| A |
| A |
| A |
| B |
| B |
| D |

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service. Please, describe the issue you have with your current code

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE (col1, col2)AS
(
   SELECT 'A',3 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'B',2 UNION ALL
   SELECT 'D',1
)

SELECT C.COL1
FROM CTE AS C
JOIN CTE AS C2 ON C.col2>=C2.col2
```